# Record count when a certain value is present in one row and a different value is not present in another row

Tags: sql

I have been tasked with a query that would tell me how many of a certain value are present when another value is not present in a separate row. The 2 rows do have a common field that will be the same when both are present. I have got to the following.

```
SELECT inci_no, count(inci_no)
FROM    inc_unit
WHERE       unit IN ('E08','ms08') and alm_date>='01/01/2013'
GROUP BY inci_no
```

So this gives me the number row for inci_no. I only need rows that have a 1 and the only unit is E08. The inci_no does not matter I have simply been using it to group by.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: two rows from the same table or two different tables?

Comment: the values are from the same table.

Comment: How do the rows relate? How would you write a self join to get the columns in the same "row"

Comment: they relate through a field named inci_no.

`code` FROM inc_unit u1, inc_unit u2
WHERE u1.inci_no = u2.inci_no `code`

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said above you could write a self join. If I understand correctly, you want rows where unit is E08 and the second row is not ms08? If so, something like this might work:

```
Select t1.inci_no, count(t1.inci_no)
From inc_unit as t1 Inner Join inc_unit as t2 On t1.inci_no = t2.inci_no
Where t1.unit = 'E08' and t2.unit <> 'ms08' and t1.alm_date>='01/01/2013'
Group by t1.inci_no
```

You might have to add something to exclude joining on itself, but this should get you started.

Comment: That is close but there can be multiple units connected to each inci_no.

Maybe this will help. We are a fire department. We need to know how many time e08 goes on medic runs without ms08. There can be multiple units on these runs.

Comment: I've edited the answer above to have the count and group by. This might work, but not knowing the data, I can't be sure.